# sequence exceeds maxvalue problem in oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

I am facing an issue with respect to sequence exceeds maxvalue while using sequence during data migration of a large set of data.

How to overcome this issue.

Do I need to recreate the table or sequence max limit can be altered?

Comment: Have you exceeded the default value (`9999999999999999999999999999`) or some lower value explicitly set?

Comment: And if a lower value, is it there for a reason? For example, you might have code that converts the sequence number to a string - for display, or as part of a column value - and could therefore length-constrained. You might also want to look at whether your migration is *supposed* to get new values - for instance, maybe you saved data as text and then are inserting that (rather than using datapump), and you meant to keep old key values, but you have a trigger that's changing them.

Comment: Check the actual `maxvalue` with `select MAX_VALUE from dba_sequences where SEQUENCE_OWNER = '....' and SEQUENCE_NAME = '.....';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sequence with `MAXVALUE` (that's what you have now):

```
SQL> create sequence seqa maxvalue 3;

Sequence created.

SQL> select seqa.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select seqa.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL> select seqa.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL> select seqa.nextval from dual;
select seqa.nextval from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08004: sequence SEQA.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated
```

Error, as expected (that's what you also have). So, **alter** and set `nomaxvalue`:

```
SQL> alter sequence seqa nomaxvalue;

Sequence altered.
```

Now it works again:

```
SQL> select seqa.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a sequence as a value in your table to uniquely identify a row you may want to consider an IDENTITY column so that's 1 less object you have to worry about

create table t1(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
...
...